# Why Google Analytics data doesn't match when date range is changed?

Tags: google-analytics

There is an issue I have seen with Google Analytics. When you are getting data from a short range, say a week, the data is not the same as when you see the same duration while getting data for a longer duration.

Sharing a sample:

I got this data from one of the reports. The data tells me the users who visited the specific section of my site last week.

[image: Active users on website in Week 19 Nov - 25 Nov]

Now when I check to compare the data of the same week with the previous week in the same report, I see a valley in the middle of the report.

[image: Active users on website in Week 19 Nov - 25 Nov]

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to sampling. 
Hover over the shield like icon on top of the dashboard to know the sampling %.

[image]

Lower the sampling %, higher the deviation.

Your website seems to be receiving lot of traffic. You might want to switch over to a premium Google Analytics account to receive unsampled reports.

Sampling kicks in whenever you apply segments, secondary dimensions or create custom reports.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192